# Lighting doesn't show in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to do point source directional lighting in OpenGL using my textbooks examples. I'm showing a rectangle centered at the origin, and doing the lighting computations in the shader. The rectangle appears, but it is black even when I try to put colored lights on it. Normals for the rectangle are all (0, 1.0, 0). I'm not doing any non-uniform scaling, so the regular model view matrix should also transform the normals.

I have code that sets the light parameters(as uniforms) and material parameters(also as uniforms) for the shader. There is no per vertex color information.

```
void InitMaterial()
{
    color material_ambient = color(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    color material_diffuse = color(1.0, 0.8, 0.0);
    color material_specular = color(1.0, 0.8, 0.0);
    float material_shininess = 100.0;

    // set uniforms for current program
    glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(Programs[lightingType], "materialAmbient"), 1, material_ambient);
    glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(Programs[lightingType], "materialDiffuse"), 1, material_diffuse);
    glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(Programs[lightingType], "materialSpecular"), 1, material_specular);
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(Programs[lightingType], "shininess"), material_shininess);
}
```

For the lights:

```
void InitLight()
{
    // need light direction and light position
    point4 light_position = point4(0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    color light_ambient = color(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
    color light_diffuse = color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    color light_specular = color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(Programs[lightingType], "lightPosition"), 1, light_position);
    glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(Programs[lightingType], "lightAmbient"), 1, light_ambient);
    glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(Programs[lightingType], "lightDiffuse"), 1, light_diffuse);
    glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(Programs[lightingType], "lightSpecular"), 1, light_specular);
}
```

The fragment shader is a simple pass through shader that sets the color to the one input from the vertex shader. Here is the vertex shader :

```
#version 150 

in vec4 vPosition;
in vec3 vNormal;
out vec4 color;

uniform vec4 materialAmbient, materialDiffuse, materialSpecular;
uniform vec4 lightAmbient, lightDiffuse, lightSpecular;
uniform float shininess;

uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main() 
{
    // Transform vertex position into eye coordinates
    vec3 pos = (modelView * vPosition).xyz;

    vec3 L = normalize(lightPosition.xyz - pos);
    vec3 E = normalize(-pos);
    vec3 H = normalize(L + E);

    // Transform vertex normal into eye coordinates
    vec3 N = normalize(modelView * vec4(vNormal, 0.0)).xyz;

    // Compute terms in the illumination equation
    vec4 ambient = materialAmbient * lightAmbient;

    float Kd = max(dot(L, N), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse = Kd * materialDiffuse * lightDiffuse;

    float Ks = pow(max(dot(N, H), 0.0), shininess);
    vec4 specular = Ks * materialSpecular * lightSpecular;

    if(dot(L, N) < 0.0) specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    gl_Position = projection * modelView * vPosition;

    color = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    color.a = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: You mentioned that your rectangle has (0,1,0) for the normals and is located at the origin and your light is located at (0,0,-1) which means that your light source is perpendicular to your object so the dot product of the light vector and the normal will be 0. You could try moving either your light or your rectangle to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: The normals are (0, 1, 0) in model space, but the light position is in eye space. I tried changing the light position to no avail.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem is but you could try a few different things to narrow it down. The first thing to try would be to set the color variable in the vertex shader to a hard coded color to verify that color is correctly being passed from the vertex to the fragment shader. The second set of things to try is to check each component of your lighting separately. First set color to just be ambient and then just diffuse and just specular to check that each component is being calculated as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's working now. The solution was to replace glUniform3fv with glUniform4fv, I guess because the glsl counterpart is a vec4 instead of a vec3. I thought that it would be able to recognize this and simply add a 1.0 to the end, but no.